# Get file path with FileProvider

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

I'm developing an app and one of the features is for the user to be able to backup their SQLite Database. The data is mainly text and images. I create a zip file with the .json and image files.

I'm using this helper class that i found online for working with Storage

```
public class FileUtils {

public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else
        if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {split[1]};
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

I successfully restore all the data/files from the .zip file but when i use the `FileUtils.getPath()` function on the restored image `Uri` i get

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist`

I assume this is because the Uri of the restored images is `content://com.appLab.AnglersDiary.provider/external_files/NEW%20EXTRACT/catchImgBackup_0_19f3eb40-8f3a-4140-b68b-745b8c820dd4.jpg`

What is a solution for handling that type of `Uri` in my app?

Comment: you dont need any "file path", what you need is most likely `InputStream` / `OutputStream` - see `ContentResolver` API docs on how to get it

Comment: The reason i need the `Uri` is because i store it in the database to access the images later on in my application

Comment: so store the `Uri` what do you need a path for if you have a full `Uri`?

Comment: Yea i store the `Uri` not the `file path` wrong term used in previous comment sorry

Comment: `I create a zip file with the .json and image files.`? Why would you? Why not just backup the database db file?

Comment: Because the database contains Uri to images. So if the user changes device he could use the .zip file to restore his data. How would i get the actual image from the Uri i store in the database if it doesn't exist on the device?

Comment: so whats your problem actually if you store the `Uri` and not "file path"s?

Comment: The problem was when i tried to backup images that were already restored i got an error because i was using `Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FileUtils.getPath(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),shareImgURI));` instead of using an `InputStream` to create the bitmap and write it to a file

Comment: ok why do you want to "decode" to `Bitmap` if all you need is to backup your files? you have `shareImgURI`, so read its content and write it to your backup zip file

Comment: To "write" the `Bitmap` to a `File` and save it in the backup `.zip` file

Comment: what for? why do you want to decode ".jpg" file to `Bitmap` and then "encode" `Bitmap` to ".jpg" file? it makes really little sense - just read `shareImgURI` content and write it to your backup zip file directly

Comment: To be honest am new to how to read/write files on android so thats what i thought was "right" but now that you mentioned it you are right. I should just copy the original ".jpg" file to my new destination?

Comment: `/NEW%20EXTRACT/` Can you find that directory on your device? And/Or the .jpg file?

Comment: yes you should copy ".jpg" -> "some zip entry"

Comment: `Get file path with FileProvider` ?? That is a nonsense subject.

Comment: @pskink I copied the existing `.jpg` to the new destination and created the `.zip` file. Now, from that zip file i can restore the data to my app again. If i try and backup the "previously restored data" i get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.appLab.AnglersDiary.provider/external_files/NEW%20EXTRACT/spotImgBackup_0_b57209c0-60c4-4e33-9396-2483d651d1c5.jpg (No such file or directory)` when i use this method `originalFile = new File(FileUtils.getPath(getActivity(),shareImgURI))`